# How to acquire an api access token for a SPA app from Azure AD B2C that doesnt require user authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

I have an existing Vue/Nuxt based SPA app that uses MSAL.js to authenticate the user and acquire access tokens for my back-end ASP.Net Core WebApi. This is all working fine. However, I have a few pages on my SPA app that can be accessed anonymously. These pages also need to make calls to the back-end API and I am wondering how I can use MSAL.js to acquire access tokens when no user is logged in? Most of the samples out there are related to redirecting the user to login first.

I know I can implement simple api key in header based authentication for those api endpoints that can be accessed anonymously, but I would prefer if I can just utilize the existing Azure AD B2c based platform to acquire a jwt access token instead for the SPA app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot acquire a token for no user.
Your front-end also cannot authenticate itself since it is a public client.

The API endpoints must allow anonymous access (no token).
The API key approach would be pretty useless since the user can see the key in the headers through F12 tools.

Comment: So are there any other options to protect these api endpoints instead of leaving them totally open i.e. anonymous access. I would prefer to have some level of token based authentication if possible.

Comment: Like I said, you would have to authenticate the user. Since your front-end application is not capable of keeping a secret, it fundamentally cannot authenticate itself, only the user could. IP address-based access restrictions could be an option?